# Como saber qual a versão em uso de um determinado pacote instalado via pip?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Eu estou começando a programar em python e tenho tentado usar as melhores práticas: virtualenv, pip, etc. 
Um dos pacotes que tenho usado (pelican) tem páginas de ajuda diferentes para cada versão. Como sei que versão estou usando?
Eu o instalei com o comando:

```
pip install pelican
```

Mas já não me lembro que versão foi baixado. Há como ver?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para ver a versão instalada de um pacote especifico use:

```
pip show pelican
```

esse comando irá mostrar a versão instalada e outras informações sobre o pacote.

Para listar a versão de todos os pacotes instalados use:

```
pip freeze
```

Esse comando irá produzir um output como este:

```
blinker==1.3
docutils==0.12
feedgenerator==1.7
Jinja2==2.7.3
MarkupSafe==0.23
pelican==3.5.0
Pygments==2.0.2
python-dateutil==2.4.2
pytz==2015.4
six==1.9.0
Unidecode==0.4.18
```

É comum usaro o pip freeze para gerar um arquivo requirements.txt, já que o formato gerado pelo output é compativel com pip install -r

Vale mencionar também o comando

```
pip list
```

Que produz um output como o exemplo abaixo:

```
blinker (1.3)
docutils (0.12)
feedgenerator (1.7)
Jinja2 (2.7.3)
MarkupSafe (0.23)
pelican (3.5.0)
pip (7.0.3)
Pygments (2.0.2)
python-dateutil (2.4.2)
pytz (2015.4)
setuptools (17.1.1)
six (1.9.0)
Unidecode (0.4.18)
```

Que não é tão diferente do pip freeze, a vantagem dele é usar junto com a opção -o:

```
pip list -o
```

Que irá listar apenas os pactoes que tem atualizações disponíveis junto com a versão instalada e a versão disponível, no formato abaixo:

```
pelican (Current: 3.4.0 Latest: 3.5.0 [wheel])
```

Answer (score 4):

Enquanto escrevia a pergunta, me lembrei da resposta:

```
pip freeze
```

Ele retorna o seguinte:

```
pelican==3.5.0
```

Eu havia usado o comando para criar o arquivo requirements.txt, que é outro lugar onde você pode olhar.

Answer (score 3):

Apenas uma alternativa, para o pip 1.3 ou superior você pode utilizar o comando `show`:

```
pip show pelican
```

---

**Fonte** [SOEn - Find which version of package is installed with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10215100/664577)

Answer (score 1):

É interessante que você guarde em um arquivo a lista de todos os pacotes instalados do seu projeto, como já sabe utilizando o comando `pip freeze` é apresentado os pacotes e as respectivas versões.

Para salvar direto em um arquivo basta usar:

```
pip freeze > requerimentos.txt
```

Para instalar os pacotes listados basta usar o comando:

```
pip install -r requirimentos.txt
```